# Tigra Calendar and Javascript DOM - How do I attach?

Tags: javascript, dom, calendar

Fine, my question is as follows. I am adding rows to a table dynamically using the DOM, and everything goes really well. However, in one of the cells I need to add this calendar: http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/
When I execute the code to add the calendar, it will create it wherever I place it and mess with everything. What I want to do, is to attach that calendar to the cell and that it executes whenever the nodes enter to the table. This is the code:

```
function addpago()
{
var i = 0;
//Create a select
var cuota=document.createElement('select');
cuota.name="cuota"+cantpagos;
cuota.id="cuota"+cantpagos;
for(i=1;i<=11;i++)
{
 cuota.options[i-1]=new Option("Cuota "+i, i);
}
//Create an input and add an event, this code works correctly
var monto=document.createElement('input');
monto.type='text';
monto.name=monto.id='monto'+cantpagos;
if(monto.addEventListener)
 monto.addEventListener("blur", sumpagos, false);
else if(monto.attachEvent)
 monto.attachEvent("onblur", sumpagos);
else
 monto.onblur = sumpagos;
monto.size=6;
//Create an input
var ncheque = document.createElement('input');
ncheque.type='text';
ncheque.name=ncheque.id='cheque'+cantpagos;
ncheque.size=10;
//Create a select
var bancos = document.createElement('select');
bancos.name=bancos.id='banco'+cantpagos;
bancos.options[0]=new Option("BANCO DE CHILE",1);
bancos.options[1]=new Option("BANCOESTADO",2);
bancos.options[2]=new Option("BANCO DE CRÉDITO E INVERSIONES",3);
bancos.options[3]=new Option("BANCO SANTANDER",4);
bancos.options[4]=new Option("BANCO ITAÚ",5);
//Create an input
var plaza = document.createElement('input');
plaza.type='text';
plaza.name=plaza.id='cheque'+cantpagos;
plaza.size=6;
//Create an input
var fecha = document.createElement('input');
fecha.type='text';
fecha.name=fecha.id='fecha'+cantpagos;
fecha.readOnly=true;
fecha.size=14;
//Create a tr, add several td's and attach each element created before to the child td's
row = document.createElement('tr');
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(cuota);
row.appendChild(cell);
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(monto);
row.appendChild(cell);
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(ncheque);
row.appendChild(cell);
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(bancos);
row.appendChild(cell);
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(plaza);
row.appendChild(cell);
cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild(fecha);
//I need to add the calendar at this point, but I can't figure out how
cell.appendChild(new tcal ({'formname': 'ingpagos', 'controlname': 'fecha'+cantpagos, 'imgpath': 'www.codesin.cl/Tigra/img/'}));
row.appendChild(cell);
document.getElementById('tabpagos').appendChild(row);
cantpagos++; //Global variable being updated
document.getElementById('cantpagos').value=cantpagos;
}
```

What should I do? Thanks beforehand...

Answer (score 0):

I've used Tigra Calendar before. Why are you adding it as a node? It's an object you just instantiate, the program takes care of modifying the DOM etc. =)

You do however need to wait to instantiate it until after the input field is IN the DOM =)

```
...
row.appendChild(cell);
document.getElementById('tabpagos').appendChild(row);
new tcal ({'formname': 'ingpagos', 'controlname': 'fecha'+cantpagos, 'imgpath': 'www.codesin.cl/Tigra/img/'})
```

Though that imgpath looks suspect so you may need to play with it some =)

Comment: There, maybe I'm confused on its usage. As you can see, I'm creating dynamically the input element that takes care of the date and adding it as a node to the table. In what moment should I instantiate the calendar?

Comment: Edited the code as you said, and all I get is the calendar image and the page loading infinitely.

Comment: Argh, i forgot, Tigra, _as written_ only works on page load because it relies on `document.write`. You'll have to change the program if you want calendars dynamically. e.g. Find the line that says `document.write('<img src="' + a_tpl.img` and re-configure it to use `innerHTML` or `appendChild`

Comment: I tried doing that: var img=document.createElement('img');
  img.id=this.s_iconId
  if(img.addEventListener)
   img.addEventListener("click", A_TCALS[this.s_id].f_toggle, false);
  else if(img.attachEvent)
   img.attachEvent("onclick", A_TCALS[this.s_id].f_toggle);
  else
   img.onclick = A_TCALS[this.s_id].f_toggle;
  img.class="tcalicon";
  img.alt="Abrir calendario";
  this.appendChild(img);
But the results are the same...

Comment: if the results are the same, check for a `document.write` in your code, first. Second, this is what I did with my `img` node:  `document.getElementById(a_cfg.controlname).parentNode.appendChild(img)`

Comment: Apparently no matter what I do, my browser doesn't get the newer version of the file.

Comment: You might want to look into clearing your cache =) FireFox will give you cache options with Ctrl(or Apple)+Shift+Delete

Comment: That was a silly mistake from my part, I was editing the wrong file. It's working now, but if I press the image the event's not there. I get this error: this.f_show is not a function
return this.b_visible ? this.f_hide() : this.f_show();